# How to multiply by a constant and then sum across rows

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, multiple-columns, constants

I am having an issue multiplying 3 columns by 3 different constants (i.e, 2,3,4, respectively) and then summing each row after applying the conversion.

I am using dplyr

```
variable <- df %>% transmute(df, sum(col1, col2*2, col3*3, col4*4))
```

Comment: This sounds like completely ordinary matrix multiplication: `matrix(1:9,3) %*% c(1,2,3)` returns: 
     [,1]
[1,]   30
[2,]   36
[3,]   42

Comment: @42 but that doesn't use dplyr which is what OP is using.

Comment: @Reeza: I suppose if this were homework and the person were required to use dplyr, then offering the matrix-multiplication operator might not be useful. But if efficiency were ever an issue, then failing to mention `%*%` would be failing to properly advise this newb.

Comment: No homework here. Just a self assigned project for the sake of applying R concepts learned through a course I took earlier this summer. Feel free to suggest any other ways to speed up the learning curve; reading material, courses, etc. @Reeza

Answer (score 2):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(a = a * 2, 
         b = b * 3, 
         c = c * 4, 
         total = a + b + c) 

#   a  b  c total
#1  2 18 44    64
#2  4 21 48    73
#3  6 24 52    82
#4  8 27 56    91
#5 10 30 60   100
```

Using `rowSums`

```
df %>%
  mutate(a = a * 2, 
         b = b * 3, 
         c = c * 4) %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(.))
```

Important to note that if we are using `rowSums`, we need to include it in the new `mutate` call and not the same one otherwise it would `sum` the original `df` and not the changed one.

Or in base R

```
df1 <- transform(df, a = a*2, b = b * 3, c = c *4)
df1$total <- rowSums(df1)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15)
```

Comment: Also sounds like a great case for a `sweep` or `Map` operation in base R - `sweep(df, 2, 2:4, \`*\`)`

Comment: I'll look into sweep

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, we can do this more compactly with `%*%`

```
df$total <- c(as.matrix(df) %*% 2:4)
df
#  a  b  c total
#1 1  6 11    64
#2 2  7 12    73
#3 3  8 13    82
#4 4  9 14    91
#5 5 10 15   100
```

Or with `crossprod`

```
df$total <- c(crossprod(t(df), 2:4))
```

--

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(df, 2:4, ~ .x * .y) %>%
     reduce(`+`) %>%
     bind_cols(df, total = .)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
variable <- df %>% 
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(new_var = sum(col1, col2*2, col3*3, col4*4))
```

Try that instead.

1. add `rowwise()` to have data analyzed at each row
2. use `mutate()` to get the new calculation